# OrientDB ETL returns error " Cannot check the existance of a database in a remote server. Please use the console or the OServerAdmin class."

Tags: etl, orientdb

### Here is my json file content

```js
"config": {
    "log": "debug",
    "parallel": false,
    "fileDirectory": "<file path>",
    "fileName": "<file name>",
    "className": "<class name>",
    "dbURL": "remote:localhost/<my deb name>",
    "dbUser": "admin",
    "dbPassword": "admin"
},
"source": {
    "file": {
        "path": "$filePath",
        "lock": false
    }
},
"extractor": {
    "row": {}
},
"transformers": [
    {
        "csv": {
            "separator": ",",
            "columnsOnFirstLine": true,
            "nullValue": "NULL"
        }
    }
],
"loader": {
    "orientdb": {
        "dbURL": "$dbURL",
        "dbUser": "$dbUser",
        "dbPassword": "$dbPassword",
        "dbAutoDropIfExists": false,
        "dbAutoCreate": false,
        "standardElementConstraints": false,
        "tx": false,
        "wal": false,
        "batchCommit": 1000,
        "dbType": "document",
        "class": "<class name>"
    }
}
```

Error message:

> OrientDB etl v.2.0.3 (build @BUILD@) www.orientechnologies.com
>   Exception in thread "main" com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OConfigurationException: Error on creating ETL processor
>           at com.orientechnologies.orient.etl.OETLProcessor.parse(OETLProcessor.java:278)
>           at com.orientechnologies.orient.etl.OETLProcessor.parse(OETLProcessor.java:188)
>           at com.orientechnologies.orient.etl.OETLProcessor.main(OETLProcessor.java:163)
>   Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: **Cannot check the existance of a database in a remote server. Please use the console or the OServerAdmin class.**
>           at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote.exists(OStorageRemote.java:273)
>           at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemoteThread.exists(OStorageRemoteThread.java:177)
>           at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.exists(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:1050)
>           at com.orientechnologies.orient.etl.loader.OOrientDBLoader.configure(OOrientDBLoader.java:246)
>           at com.orientechnologies.orient.etl.OETLProcessor.configureComponent(OETLProcessor.java:494)
>           at com.orientechnologies.orient.etl.OETLProcessor.parse(OETLProcessor.java:251)
>           ... 2 more

Answer (score 0):

2.0.3 i a very old version. If your stuck with that, my suggestion is to load using plocal. So, switch off the server, point the etl to the storage with plocal: and then switch on the server again. A massive load of data over plocal is faster than remote.
If you can update to 2.1.5, It has some improvement on the CSV extractor to be used instead of row.

Comment: I changed the db but still I'm getting that same error (db version 2.1.5)

Comment: Did you try with plocal? If you go remote, you need to create the db on server BEFORE running ETL. So enter in studio or in console and create the db.

Comment: I tried with plocal it's working but i need to stop the db for the ETL process. But i need to do the ETL process without stopping the database. How can i do that?